# Rails 4 x Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker: replace default datetime_select with datetimepicker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, datetimepicker

In my Rails 4 app, which already uses Bootstrap 3, I just added [Datetimepicker by eonasdan](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/).

I carefully followed the instructions offered [here](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/#rails) and [there](https://github.com/TrevorS/bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails) to install the plugin.

Here is my setup:

## Gemfile

```
gem 'momentjs-rails'
gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails'
```

## application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap/dropdown
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

## application.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import 'bootstrap/theme';
@import 'bootstrap-datetimepicker';
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "simple_calendar";
@import "custom.scss";
@import "custom/**/*"
```

And I do have restarted my server.

Now, I am trying to use the plugin in my `Posts#New` and `Posts#Edit` views form, to replace the current `datetime_select` field:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :date, "DATE" %>
  <%= f.datetime_select :date %>
</div>
```

This is where I am after my first attempt:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
    <%= f.label :date, "DATE & TIME" %>
      <%= f.text_field :date, :class => "form-control"%>
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Which gives me the following elements in the view:

[image]

Although the design is far from perfect, for now, this is not what I am concerned about.

The real problem is that, when I create a post, the `date` attribute (which is a `datetime` data type) is set to `nil`, instead of the value chosen in the `datetimepicker`.

I looked for similar situations online, and the closest I have found is [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31623469/bootstrap-3-datetimepicker-with-rails-form-for).

Unfortunately, it is based on slim forms, and I don't know how to "translate" them into regular forms, to be used in a `erb.html` file.

Any idea of what is wrong with my code?

—————

**UPDATE**: I have found a way that is actually saving the date to the database when the post is created:

```
<div class="form-group" id="post_date_time">
      <%= f.label :date, "DATE & TIME" %>
      <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
        <%= f.text_field :date, :class => "form-control"%>
          <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
      });
    </script>
```

However, it does not seem to work properly on the edit form, since I don't get the datetimepicker populated with the date of the post. Am I missing something here?

—————

Comment: In your chrome dev console what are the params being passed back to your controller? I think you will find that it is not sending 'date', but one of 'starts_at'.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb reply... but I can't seem to see anything in my dev console. I opened it, created a post, and nothing appeared. Am I doing the right thing? Also, why do you say I should see `starts_at` in it, while I don't have this string anywhere in my code? Thanks a lot for your help ;)

Comment: If you open up the chrome dev tools and go to the 'network' tab when you hit submit on your form you should see a post to your controller and you can see the details there. Or you can put a debugger in on your controller and check the params when it hits it. I say that because I actually had a similar issue and that is what I found. Not sure why, but it was not the field I was expecting it to be.

Comment: Ok, cool. Thanks for helping others who have the same problem ;) The only thing I could find in my network was: `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="post[date]"` Is that what we are looking for? Let me know if it is easier to jump on the chat to fix this, I am happy to.

Comment: Sure, we can do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't have the chat link on my end yet, maybe we have not commented enough on the post to get access to it ;) Anyway, I have found a way to make it work for `Posts#New` but then I can't retrieve the date in `Posts#Edit`. Did you run into a similar problem too?

Comment: I created a basic working example of the bootstrap datetimepicker with the edit working, let me know if this helps: https://github.com/DustinFisher/datetimepicker-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the datetime populated on your edit page you can do this in the javascript setup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
      defaultDate: "<%= @post.date %>",
      format: "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a Z"
    });
  });
</script>
```

I have the working code here: [Github - Rails Datetimepicker Example](https://github.com/DustinFisher/datetimepicker-example)

Comment: What about the Rails 5? I need to format it to make it possible to be stored instead on storing nil value.