# Rails 4 x Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker: design is not good

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to apply the Bootstrap3 `Datetimepicker` in my Rails4 app.

But the layout is not good like as this page (in the middle of the question image). [Rails 4 x Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker: replace default datetime_select with datetimepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529820/rails-4-x-bootstrap-3-datetimepicker-replace-default-datetime-select-with-datet)

It would be appreciated if you could give me any suggestion.

**_xxx_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for(@schedule) do |f| %>
  <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker">
    <%= f.label :departure_date %>
    <%= f.text_field :departure_date, class: 'form-control' %>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({format:'MMM-DD-YYYY'});
    });
  </script>
    ...
```

**SOLVED!!!**

The layout was as I expected after moving `f.label` to outside of `<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker">`.

```
  ...
  <%= f.label :departure_date %> 
  <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker">
    <%= f.text_field :departure_date, class: 'form-control' %>
  ...
```

Comment: Solved my own question at the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this simply nice

```
<%= f.text_field :departure_date, class: 'form-control', id: 'datepicker'%>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
});
```

Just click input field then show calendar